# Inverse Jordan Decomposition Matlab code?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

I did Jordan decomposition of a matrix by using this code: 

`A = [1 -3 -2; -1  1 -1; 2 4 5];
[V, J] = jordan(A)`

Now I need to do inverse Jordan decomposition to get original matrix A. How can I do that in Matlab?

Comment: A Jordan decomposition of $A$ gives you $V$ and $J$, so that $A = VJV^{-1}$. You can easy see, how to get from $V$ and $J$ back to $A$.

Comment: I tried this code `IJ = (1\V)*(1\J)*(V)` but didn't get the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Jordan decomposition of $A$ gives you matrices $V$ and $J$, such that $A = VJV^{-1}$. 
And that is exactly what you need to do, to get back to $A$!
Just use "A2 = (V*J)/V;" and you will get the result.

What you did in the comments (1\V) is not a valid MATLAB syntax for the inverse of a Matrix. 
I have to admint, that \ is also not correct in that case, since it is left inversion. "/" is therefore correct! (see code below)

I was made aware, that jordan is from the symbolic toolbox and therefore $J$ and $V$ will not be easy to handle. In that case, you could use the [double](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html) command of the toolbox. 
Therefore this will work quite well

> [V,J]=jordan(A);
>   V2=double(V);
>   J2=double(J);
>   A2=V2*J2/V2;
>   max(max(abs(A-A2)))

Comment: nope... the result is wrong!

Comment: I just realised, that "jordan" is from the symbolic toolbox. This makes everything worse... Be right back with results!

Comment: Edited my answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got the correct result. Just thinking why am I devoted?